# Error when answering a confirmation in bash

Tags: bash

I am making a simple confirmation prompt, here is the code

```
read -r -p "Are You Sure? [Y/n] " input

case $input in
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
        echo "Yes"
        ;;

    [nN][oO]|[nN])
        echo "No"
            ;;

    *)
    echo "Invalid input..."
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

But when I answer anything whether it is valid or not, it will show errors

```
Quang-Anhs-iPhone-3GS:~ root# /var/mobile/Testarea/confirm.sh
Are You Sure? [Y/n] y
/var/mobile/Testarea/confirm.sh: line 1: read: `input
': not a valid identifier
/var/mobile/Testarea/confirm.sh: line 2: 
: command not found
/var/mobile/Testarea/confirm.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'
/var/mobile/Testarea/confirm.sh: line 3: `case $input in
'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Windows line terminators?

Comment: What? I'm doing on jailbroken iPhone

Comment: How did you create the script? Can you add a hexdump of the first few lines?

Comment: Can you provide more details? iOS also use UNIX so it will function like Terminal on Mac OS X

Comment: In GNU Bash 4.3.46 works fine.  The error shows that `input` is not a valid identifier.  Have you ever tried to change it (to `answer`, for example)?

Comment: can you detail it? I'm still a bash beginner

Comment: Try to change `input` to `answer` and `$input` to `$answer`.

Comment: Still same error

Comment: What's the name of the application you use to start this script?

Comment: Im using Mobile Terminal on cydia

Comment: I get the same error when I add Ctrl-M at the end of each line.

Comment: Try execute `help` in terminal and look the list for `read` command.

Comment: I found alternative solution in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what's wrong with iOS but I found an alternative.
This alternative works like a selection menu

```
function yes {
    echo "Yes"
}

all_done=0
while (( !all_done )); do
    options=("Yes" "Exit")

    echo "Are you sure "
    COLUMNS=12
    select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $REPLY in
            1) yes; break ;;
            2) all_done=1; break ;;
            *) echo "Invalid input..." ;;
        esac
    done
done

echo "Exiting"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more simple that you think, first guarantee you are using bash and just try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Are You Sure? [Y/n] " input

input=$(echo "$input" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]")

case $input in
    Y*|S*|E*)
        echo "Yes"
        ;;

    N*|O*)
        echo "No"
            ;;

    *)
    echo "Invalid input..."
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Mobile Terminal on cydia have no builtin function `read`, so this script couldn't be started.

Comment: Actually it has